# Get slickgrid working with paging, checkbox selection, sorting, and filtering with large data sets?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, slickgrid

I have a slickgrid set up, and am trying to pass 500,000 records to it or less (500k is the absolute maximum).

I have paging, sorting, inline column filtering, and the check box row selection all set up and working with a few caveats.

Browser crashes or asks (are you sure you want to keep running this long-running script?) whenever I load any data over 100k records in IE8 and any instance of FireFox. (IE8 is used company wide where I am, so I don't have the option to tell them to upgrade at the moment)

I am using MVC, the data is coming from multiple ajax requests since json data can only be so long.

The effect I'm going for, is when a user selects a file from "ddlFiles" the grid is populated based on the results of the selection.

The front-end code looks like such:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var grid;
    var finalData = [];
    var columnFilters = {};
    function getDate(jsonDate) {
        // added checks for undefs.. djweaver 
        if (typeof jsonDate === 'undefined') {
            return "01/01/0000";
        }
        var dt1 = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substring(6, jsonDate.length - 2)));
        var month = (dt1.getMonth() + 1);
        var day = dt1.getDate();
        var year = dt1.getFullYear();

        if (month < 10) { month = "0" + month; }
        if (day < 10) { day = "0" + day; }

        var dt1String = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
        return dt1String;
    }
    $("#myGrid").height(($("#ddlPage").val() * 25) + 59);
    $("#ddlClients").change(function () {
        $("#loadingDialog").dialog('open');
        $("#progressbar").fadeIn('fast');
        if (finalData.length > 0) {
            grid.destroy();
        }
        while (finalData.length > 0) {
            finalData.pop();
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#ddlFiles").val(0);
            $("#myGrid").empty();
            $("#loadingDialog").dialog('close');
            $("#progressbar").fadeOut('fast');
        }, 5000);
    });
    $("#ddlFiles").change(function () {
        if ($("ddlFiles").val() != 0) {
            if (finalData.length > 0) {
                grid.destroy();
            }
            while (finalData.length > 0) {
                finalData.pop();
            }
            $("#myGrid").empty();
            $(".selEdit").show();
            $("#loadingDialog").dialog('open');
            $("#progressbar").fadeIn('slow');
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "Intake/getDataInfo",
                dataType: "text",
                data: { numRecords: $("#ddlFiles").val() },
                cache: false,
                success: function (info) {
                    var counter = (info / 5000) + 1;
                    for (var x = 0; x <= counter + 1; x++) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "Intake/getData",
                            dataType: "json",
                            data: { counter: x },
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (json) {
                                $.merge(finalData, json);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    waitOnData(info);

                }
            });
        }
    });
    var timeoutId = null;
    function waitOnData(totalCount) {
        var percent = (finalData.length / totalCount)*100;
        $("#progressbar").width(percent + "%");
        if (percent < 100) {
            timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
                waitOnData(totalCount);
            }, 300);
        } else {
            popGrid(finalData);
        }
    }

    function popGrid(data) {

        var dateFormatter = function (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
            return getDate(value);
        };
        var dataView; 
        var columns = [];
        var checkboxSelector = new Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn({});
        columns.push(checkboxSelector.getColumnDefinition());
        columns.push(
            { id: "LastName", name: "Last Name", field: "LastName", sortable: true, width: 75 },
            { id: "FirstName", name: "First Name", field: "FirstName", sortable: true, width: 75 },
            { id: "Hicn", name: "Hicn", field: "Hicn", sortable: true, width: 75 },
            { id: "DOB", name: "DOB", field: "DOB", sortable: true, formatter: dateFormatter, width: 75 },
            { id: "PlanEffDate", name: "Plan Eff Date", field: "PlanEffDate", formatter: dateFormatter, sortable: true, width: 80 },
            { id: "PrimaryCarrier", name: "Primary Carrier", field: "PrimaryCarrier", sortable: true, width: 100 },
            { id: "SecondaryCarrier", name: "Secondary Carrier", field: "SecondaryCarrier", sortable: true, width: 100 },
            { id: "SecondaryId", name: "SecondaryId", field: "SecondaryId", sortable: true, width: 80 }
        );

        var options = {
            editable: true,
            multiColumnSort: false,
            enableCellNavigation: true,
            showHeaderRow: true,
            headerRowHeight: 30,
            asyncEditorLoading: true,
            forceFitColumns: true,
            explicitInitialization: true
        };

        function filter(item) {
            for (var columnId in columnFilters) {
                if (columnId !== undefined && columnFilters[columnId] !== "") {
                    var c = grid.getColumns()[grid.getColumnIndex(columnId)];
                    var itemString = item[c.field].toString();
                    if (itemString.indexOf('/Date') >= 0) { itemString = getDate(itemString) }
                    if (itemString.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(columnFilters[columnId].toString().toLowerCase(),0) === -1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }        
        dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView({ inlineFilters: true });
        grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", dataView, columns, options);
        var columnpicker = new Slick.Controls.ColumnPicker(columns, grid, options);
        grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel({ selectActiveRow: false }));
        grid.registerPlugin(checkboxSelector);
        var pager = new Slick.Controls.Pager(dataView, grid, $("#pager"));
        dataView.onRowCountChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            grid.updateRowCount();
            grid.render();
        });
        dataView.onRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            grid.invalidateRows(args.rows);
            grid.render();
        });
        grid.onHeaderRowCellRendered.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            $(args.node).empty();
            if (args.column.id != "_checkbox_selector") {
                $("<input type='text'>")
                                            .data("columnId", args.column.id)
                                            .val(columnFilters[args.column.id])
                                            .appendTo(args.node);
            }
        });
        $(grid.getHeaderRow()).delegate(":input", "change keyup", function (e) {
            var columnId = $(this).data("columnId");
            if (columnId != null) {
                columnFilters[columnId] = $.trim($(this).val());
                dataView.refresh();
            }
        });
        grid.onHeaderRowCellRendered.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            $(args.node).empty();
            if (args.column.id != "_checkbox_selector") {
                $("<input type='text'>")
                                .data("columnId", args.column.id)
                                .val(columnFilters[args.column.id])
                                .appendTo(args.node);
            }
        });
        grid.onSort.subscribe(function (e, args) {
            var isDate = (finalData[0][args.sortCol.field].indexOf("/Date") >= 0) ? true : false;
            dataView.fastSort(args.sortCol.field, isDate, args.sortAsc);
            //grid.invalidate(); 
            $("#progressbar").fadeOut('fast');
            $("#loadingDialog").dialog('close');
        });
        dataView.syncGridSelection(grid, true);
        grid.init();
        dataView.beginUpdate();
        dataView.setItems(data, "Id");
        dataView.setFilter(filter);
        dataView.setPagingOptions({ pageSize: $("#ddlPage").val() });
        dataView.endUpdate();
        $("#progressbar").fadeOut('fast');
        $("#loadingDialog").dialog('close');
    }
    $("#chkPage").click(function () {
        grid.setSelectedRows("0,1,2,3,4");
        alert($.session.get("selected"));
    });
    function SetPager() {
        $('#txtPagingChange').keyup(function () {
            var number = $("#txtPagingChange").val();
            dataView.setPagingOptions({ pageNum: number - 1 });
            $('#txtPagingChange').focus();
            $('#txtPagingChange').val('');
            $('#txtPagingChange').val(number);
        });
    }
    $(function () {
        $(".selEdit").hide();
        $("#btnConfigs").click(function () {
            $("#ConfigDialog").dialog('open');
        });
        $("#ConfigDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 350,
            height: 135,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            beforeclose: function (event, ui) { return false; },
            dialogClass: "noclose",
            show: {
                effect: "slide",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "fold",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });

        $("#btnOverrideConfirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 135,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            beforeclose: function (event, ui) { return false; },
            dialogClass: "noclose",
            show: {
                effect: "slide",
                duration: 1000
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "fold",
                duration: 1000
            }
        });

        $("#btnSubmitGrid").click(function () {
            $("#btnOverrideConfirm").dialog('open');
        });
        $("#btnSubmitConfig").click(function () {
            $("#myGrid").height(($("#ddlPage").val() * 25) + 59);
            dataView.setPagingOptions({ pageSize: $("#ddlPage").val() });
            $("#ConfigDialog").dialog('close');
        });
        $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: false });
        $("#loadingDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            width: 730,
            height: 100,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            beforeclose: function (event, ui) { return false; },
            dialogClass: "noclose",
            show: {
                effect: "puff",
                duration: 10
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "slide",
                duration: 10
            }
        });
    })

</script>
```

Comment: You'll have to do some kind of lazy loading, but haven't seen any official code for doing that and I would be interested in doing that too some day. If you are passing the data through your intranet network, that would be faster, though if you're doing it through regular internet, well of wow that would be crazy. I mean that would be a lot of data....at least try to compress your data before sending it to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the idea of la ghiscoding's suggestion, you have to implement lazyloading on the data.

Here is just an idea on how you could implement the pagination (not using Slick.Controls.Pager):

- implement the paging/limiting of data to be fetched on the backend part and just pass the page number from the ajax request
- on the front end part, fetch the paging info first (total no. of rows, total no. of pages)
- add 2 buttons for the previous and next page, when a previous/next button is clicked, fetch the data and pass page number( current page minus/plus 1), disable the previous/next when there are no more previous/next page to fetch
- save the current page in a global var/object in your javascript
- refresh the grid every after fetch (grid is only containing and displaying the rows of the current page)

Doing this means you won't have to render/fetch all the data and store it into the grid at once. However, other features that you can do with your data in the grid is also being done partially (e.g. sorting would only sort the current items in your grid and not all final data)